# Show active accounts in Excel Pivottable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to show revenue per month for a number of rental contracts that run for months or even years. Those contracts have a start and end date and I want to show per Month how much is coming for a given year.

[This is the source table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa63a.png)

[This is what I want it to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfyYU.png)

Have only managed to do it in an ugly way with an intermediate table but there must be a proper way to do this in a Pivot table, right?

Thx for your help!

Have tried many ways in a pivot chart but using the start and end date as filters is giving me very odd results with only data being shown when a contract starts or ends.

Comment: I don't see how a pivot table could take your current data and extrapolate months and years from two columns. This would be much easier if your data were only four columns (customer, contract, revenue, date) where date represents each month the contract is valid. If you had a calendar table, I suppose you could use something like power query to get your data in that shape.

Comment: One date field that represents multiple months? How would that work?

Comment: No, one row per customer-contract-month. So customer 5 with contract 9 would have 4 rows (Nov'22 thru Feb'23).

Comment: Hmm ok, that could mean many rows for multi-year contract. I'll see whether thats more convenient or whether I do keep that cal table with a column for each year.

Comment: Another idea would be using a SUMIFS formula, but not sure if that provides the output you want. For example, let's pretend Column A is monthly Review, Columns B and C are your start and dates. Then elsewhere (column F), you have a column with each row being a month between your min and max (like 1/1/2022 thru 10/1/2024 would be 35 rows). This would be cell G2 formula: `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<="&F2,C:C,">="&F2)`. Drag it down. But again, not sure if that's what you really want.